# Insert and return both number of rows inserted (non-duplicates) and id of record (new or duplicate)

Tags: c#, mysql, insert, insert-update

I have an insert method in C#. Essentially the following, where url is a unique contraint in the table:

```
INSERT INTO pages
(url) VALUES ('http://www.google.com');
```

In a single query I would like to get:

1. The id of either the inserted row or the entry that already exists
2. The number of rows inserted (not counting duplicates that already exist)

I was originally calling the insert as seen above using ExecuteNonQuery and catching the MySQL duplicate exception (could have used INSERT IGNORE but it is comforting to know it is not failing because another part of the query). This allowed me to get an accurate count of the number of rows actually inserted, but did not provide a way of retrieving the id in the case of a duplicate (command.LastInsertedId returns -1 if the row is a duplicate).

I then changed the statement to the following:

```
INSERT INTO pages
(url) VALUES ('http://www.google.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id= LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

This updates the command.LastInsertedId property correctly, but of course no longer throws an exception and because of the UPDATE catch returns 1 from ExecuteNonQuery and seemingly provides no way of determining if the row as inserted or is a duplicate.

What is my best option in determining both id of record and number of inserted rows using the .NET (C#) adapter, preferably with a single statement?

Is there a way I can set the number of rows affected in my query? Is there a method that will provide me both pieces of information without a significant performance dip?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in mySql, but i would go for an INSERT + SELECT approach. Something like:

```
declare @prevID <column type>
select @prevID = id from pages where url = 'http://www.google.com'
if @prevID is null
begin
    insert into pages(url) values ('http://www.google.com')
    select 1, @@identity
end
else
    select 0, @prevID
```